# How to match double quote in python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I use this statement `result=re.match(r"\[.+\]",sentence)` to match `sentence="[balabala]"`. But I always get `None`. Why? I tried many times and online regex test shows it works.

Comment: is `"` part of the string like "`"[balabala]"`"  ?

Comment: There's no `"` in `[balabala]`. And if there was, there's no `"` in `\[.+\]`. Can you clarify?

Comment: sorry , I will delete it

Comment: That `sentence` and that `result` seem to work fine.

Comment: yeah, I use 're.findall()' as your answer and the problem was solved

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Those double-quotes in your regular expression are delimiting the string rather than part of the regular expression. If you want them to be part of the actual expression, you'll need to add more, and escape them with a backslash (`r"\"\[.+\]\""`). Alternatively, enclose the string in single quotes instead (`r'"\[.+\]"'`).
2. `re.match()` only produces a match if the expression is found at the *beginning* of the string. Since, in your example, there is a double quote character at the beginning of the string, and the regular expression doesn't include a double quote, it does not produce a match. Try `re.search()` or `re.findall()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Regx

```
["][\w\s]+["]
```

This will match any words enclosed within duble quotes, for example `"asd"`

```
s='hello dear "Akhil", how are you?'
print(re.findall(r'["][\w\s]+["]',s)
```

This will return `"Akhil"` in a list type.